# Clear listview on back button pressed in android

Tags: android, listview, back-button

I don't know how to clear dynamic listview[coming from database].. There is one activity for search displaying list view if I click on back button and search again.. the previous search data will as is it is, and new search data added to that list.. It mean listview not clearing on re-search, the same data is continuously displaying again and again..

I have tried to finish activity on back button pressed, still listview not clearing and same record displays multiple time as many time as I search that record..
Any solution for that..?? ANy help will be appreciate...
Thanks..